# Setting a node to a node defined in Red-Black Tree Class

Tags: c++, class, nodes, red-black-tree

I have created a class for a Red-Black tree class that contains a private `RBNode* Tnil` defined in the class like so:

```
#ifndef RBTREE_H
#define RBTREE_H
#include "RBNode.h"

class RBTree{
private:
    RBNode* Tnil;

    void RBLeftRotate(RBNode* x);
    void RBRightRotate(RBNode* x);
    void RBInsertFixUp(RBNode* z);
public:
    void RBInsert(int value);
    //Other functions
};
#endif
```

In my insert function I am trying to create `RBNode* y` and have it point to the `RBNode* Tnil` defined in the class itself.

I have tried the following:

```
    RBNode* y = new RBNode();
    RBTree::Tnil = y;
```

as well as:

```
    RBNode* y = new RBNode();
    RBTree::Tnil = y;
```

*Note: This `RBNode` constructor sets the nodeValue to some arbitrary value, both children to NULL and the color to black.

How could I correctly point `RBNode* y` to `Tnil`?

Comment: RBNode* y = Tnil;  This has to be in a member function of RBTree, though, since Tnil is private.

Comment: So should I create a "setter" function to set Tnil to y?

Comment: If you are going to use a nil node why not just make that nil node be a member of the class?

Comment: Didn't I do that by declaring `RBNode* Tnil` in the class?

Comment: No, you are using an (as far as I can see) an uninitialized pointer, if you had it be an actual node it would be declared "RBNode nil;" and you would set a pointer as "y= &nil;" and check with "if(&nil == y)". Personally I prefer to just use a nullptr rather than an explicit nil node.